# URL rewrite in lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd

I have the following query:

```
update234ae5.php?q=1&q=2....
```

must be rewritten to:

```
update.php?cond=234ae5&q=1&q=2....
```

I use:

```
"^/update(([a-zA-Z0-9]+))"  =>  "/update.php?cond=$1"
```

How can I add the rest of url string, because my url is rewritten to

```
update.php?cond=234ae5&
```

without the rest of params

In Apache I use

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)  
RewriteRule ^/update([0-9a-z]+).php /update.php?cond=$1&%1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the lighttpd documentation states](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModRewrite):

> If you wanna pass the Query String
>   (?foo=bar) to the rewrite destination
>   you have to explicitly match it:

So you'll want something like:

```
"^/update([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.php(\?(.+))?" => "/update.php?cond=$1&$3"
```

Comment: Forgot to include the ".php" part in the match.  Edited post to correct.