# Lighttpd pass get parameters with mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, get, lighttpd

I got a problem with mod_rewrite.

**Environment:**

PHP version: 5.2.6

Lighttpd version: 1.4.24

---

There's a PHP script which takes parameters like this:

*Get information (GET)*

*NOTE: The number of parameters varies and is not specified yet*

`remote.host/api.php?method=get&format=json&q=query1?q2=query2`

*Set information (POST)*

```
remote.host/api.php
parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2
```

*api.php script*

```
<?php
    var_dump($_GET);
    var_dump($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
?>
```

**Problem**

Now I want to modify the get and set URLs a bit like this:

*Get information*

```
remote.host/api/get/json/?q1=query1&q2=query2
```

For this purpose I made the following rule in the lighttpd.conf:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
"(?<=/get/json/\?)(?<=\?).*" => "/api.php?method=get&format=json"
)
```

**UPDATED, READ EDIT**

For the query `http://remote.host/api/get/json/?test1=1&test2=foo` the script gives back

```
array(2) {
["method"]=>
string(3) "get"
["format"]=>
string(4) "json"
}
string(32) "/api/get/json/?test1=1&test2=foo"
```

The desired result would be that all parameters are in `$_GET` by default.
I have read something about passing the get parameters here [URL rewrite in lighttpd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902394/url-rewrite-in-lighttpd)
but I don't know how to apply it for my rule and if it would work with any number of parameters.

**EDIT:**

My new rule looks like this now:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
"^/api/(set)/(json|xml)/(\?(.+))?" => "api.php?method=$1&format=$2&$3"
)
```

Now, the api.php output is:

```
array(4) {
  ["method"]=>
  string(3) "set"
  ["format"]=>
  string(4) "json"
  ["?test1"]=>
  string(4) "foo"
  ["test2"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}
string(35) "/api/set/json/?test1=foo&test2=bar"
```

This looks much better now, but how can I get rid of the "?" in the 2nd array element?

Thanks for your help!